# Logitech webcam motion detection, wake on motion possible?

Tags: motion-detection

My Logitech C270 appears to be capable of motion detection, but the only thing the software can do is record when motion is picked up.

If possible I would like my computer in sleep mode to wake up as I sit down at my desk, if the camera detects motion. While I know this is completely unnecessary, you have to admit its a pretty cool little project.

Is this type of thing possible? Running Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only feasible if the entire motion detection is done in webcam and wake up the host via USB.  As such, I believe most consume grade webcam requires the PC to assist in the motion detection, so it won't work if the PC is suspended.